# Group by T-SQL vs. MySQL (single column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate

I am new to SQL Server/used to MySQL databases and I am running into an issue that I never ran into with MySQL. I am looking to pull all current policy numbers, the name of the company/person it belongs to, their total premium, and whether or not they have what we call 'equipment breakdown' coverage. This is all pretty simple, the issue I am having is with grouping. I want to group by one column only, aka one distinct policy number, the company name, a sum of the premium (it is possible to have several premium amounts both negative and positive so I want to sum these to see what the true total is), and a simple Yes or No column for equipment breakdown.

Here is the query I am running:

```
SELECT pol_num as policy_number, 
insd_name as insureds_name, 
SUM(amt) as 'total_premium',
(SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown'
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'    
    END) as 'equipment_breakdown'
FROM bapu.dbo.fact_prem
WHERE '2014-05-06' between d_pol_eff and d_pol_exp
AND amt_type = 'Premium'
AND amt_desc = 'Written Premium'
GROUP BY pol_num
ORDER BY policy_number
```

I get the an error saying that I need to group by insd_name and cvg_desc as well, but I DON'T want that as it gives me duplicate policy numbers.

**Here is an example of what I get when I group everything it tells me to:**

```
policy_number   insureds_name       total_premium      equipment_breakdown

001             company a           0.00               n
001             company a           25,000.00          n
001             company a          -10,000.00          n
002             company b           100.00             y
002             company b           10,000.00          y
```

**Here is an example of the results I want:**

```
policy_number   insureds_name       total_premium      equipment_breakdown

001             company a           15,000.00          n
002             company b           10,100.00          y
```

Basically, I just want to group by the policy number and sum the premium amounts. Above is how I would achieve this in MySQL, how can I achieve the results I am looking for in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an aggregate function on the fields you don't want to group by. A simple one to use is `MAX` which works with most types;

```
SELECT pol_num as policy_number, 
MAX(insd_name) as insureds_name, 
SUM(amt) as 'total_premium',
(SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(cvg_desc) = 'Equipment Breakdown'
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'    
    END) as 'equipment_breakdown'
FROM bapu.dbo.fact_prem
WHERE '2014-05-06' between d_pol_eff and d_pol_exp
AND amt_type = 'Premium'
AND amt_desc = 'Written Premium'
GROUP BY pol_num
ORDER BY policy_number
```

The reason SQL Server wants this is that it likes to give deterministic answers, for example

```
column_a | column_b
1        | 1
1        | 2
```

...grouped by only `column_a` would in MySQL give either 1 or 2 as an answer for `column_b`, while SQL Server wants you to tell it explicitly which one to use.

Comment: @cory and Joachim Isaksson, these both worked, thank you very much. Am I crazy though? From what I remember, none of this is necessary in MySQL, you can just group by a single column without much fuss.

Comment: @user3365317 Yes, the problem is the one at the bottom of my answer, MySQL can give different results for the same query run twice. SQL Server has stricter (and standard) grouping rules that makes it return the same answer every time.

Comment: @user3365317 You're not necessarily crazy, but MySQL is just plain WRONG in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't require all non-aggregate fields to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, even though not doing so can yield unexpected results.  SQL Server requires this, so you are forced to decide how you want to handle multiple `insd_name` values for a given `pol_num`, you can use `MAX()`, `MIN()`, or if the values are always the same, just add them to your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  pol_num AS policy_number
      , MAX(insd_name) AS insureds_name
      , SUM(amt) AS 'total_premium'
      , MAX(CASE WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown' THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END) AS 'equipment_breakdown'
FROM    bapu.dbo.fact_prem
WHERE   '2014-05-06' BETWEEN d_pol_eff AND d_pol_exp
        AND amt_type = 'Premium'
        AND amt_desc = 'Written Premium'
GROUP BY pol_num
ORDER BY policy_number
```

Or:

```
SELECT  pol_num AS policy_number
      , insd_name AS insureds_name
      , SUM(amt) AS 'total_premium'
      , CASE WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown' THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END AS 'equipment_breakdown'
FROM    bapu.dbo.fact_prem
WHERE   '2014-05-06' BETWEEN d_pol_eff AND d_pol_exp
        AND amt_type = 'Premium'
        AND amt_desc = 'Written Premium'
GROUP BY pol_num
       , insd_name
       , CASE WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown' THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END
ORDER BY policy_number
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `cvg_desc` column is probably what's messing you up. You want to group by the resulting `Y` or `N` from your `CASE` statement, but SQL server is grouping by the original `cvg_desc` column. You could approach this in a way that resolves the `CASE` statement before it groups. For example, wrap the main query in a common table expression (CTE), which is sort of like an inline-view. Then with the equipment breakdown column reduced to just a `Y` or an `N`, a subsequent query from the CTE with your `SUM` aggregation on `premium` should give you the results you desire:

```
WITH Policies(policy_number, insureds_name, premium, equipment_breakdown) AS
(
    SELECT 
        pol_num
        ,insd_name
        ,amt
        ,(CASE WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) 
            AS 'equipment_breakdown'
    FROM
        bapu.dbo.fact_prem
    WHERE 
        '2014-05-06' BETWEEN d_pol_eff AND d_pol_exp
        AND 
        amt_type = 'Premium'
        AND 
        amt_desc = 'Written Premium'
)
SELECT
    policy_number
    ,insureds_name
    ,SUM(premium) AS total_premium
    ,equipment_breakdown
FROM
    Policies
GROUP BY
    policy_number
    ,insureds_name
    ,equipment_breakdown
```

Comment: Note, Gary's answer does this effectively by putting the `CASE` statement right in the `GROUP BY`, which is an option, but I prefer this way as there's no duplication to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write this as below -- did not test

```
SELECT pol_num as policy_number, 
insd_name as insureds_name, 
SUM(amt) as total_premium
CASE 
    WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown'
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'    
END as equipment_breakdown
FROM bapu.dbo.fact_prem
WHERE '2014-05-06' between d_pol_eff and d_pol_exp
AND amt_type = 'Premium'
AND amt_desc = 'Written Premium'

GROUP BY 
pol_num, policy_number, 
CASE 
    WHEN cvg_desc = 'Equipment Breakdown'
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'    
END
ORDER BY policy_number
```